# Reverse Question Mark in Boolean Value IOS NSUserdefaults

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard, boolean, nsuserdefaults

I have an app with story board and navigation controller, I want to pop up a agreement view if user launches the app first time,

in Appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //app launched first time
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"firstTime"];
    BOOL firstTime = [prefs boolForKey:@"firstTime"];
    NSLog(@"firstTime %c",firstTime);

     //check if user has agreed agreement or not
    if ( firstTime==YES) {

        //replace and push rootview manually
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController.storyboard;

        UIViewController *loginController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AgreementViewController"];

        [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:loginController animated:YES];

    return NO;
    }else

     return YES;
}
```

In `Nslog` for first time I get a `reverse question mark sign`, I guess it is neither set to yes or no

So how can I set a Boolean value,save it in ios device and call it everytime app launches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the NSUserDefaults method, registerDefaults. That method allows you to set a value for a default (YES in your case), that is only used if the user has not changed the value. Once the user changes the value to NO, the registered default will no longer have any effect.

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],@"firstTime", nil];
BOOL firstTime = [prefs boolForKey:@"firstTime"];
 //check if user has agreed agreement or not
if ( firstTime==YES) { .....
```

Then, somewhere later when the user has done what you want, you would set the value of the key, "firstTime", to NO in the usual way.

Answer (score 3):

change `%c` to `%i` in the log statement